# RSA encryption by supplying modulus and exponent

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption, rsa

I am creating a C# Winforms application which POSTs data to a server over HTTPS.

The login mechanism is supposed to be like this:

1. I send the username to the server, it responds with rsa-modulus and rsa-exponent
2. I encrypt the password using these given parameters and send username + password to the server for authentication

I have tried the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class, but I cannot find samples or anything said on **how we can do the encryption using a given modulus and exponent?**.

I think that without specifying any values, its doing default encryption parameters..

So if anybody has done this before, can they give me some hints please? thanks

**UPDATE**: according to the suggestion by Mr. Carsten Konig, . I have tried to do it with RSAParameters and `RSA.ImportParameters`, but it returns a "BAD DATA" error with cryptographic exception. My code is given below.

I have also tried `RSA.FromXmlString(mykey)`; (where `mykey` contains an xml string with modulus and exp) but I also get a "BAD DATA" errror with cryptographic exception... any idea anybody? or if its some microsoft bug, can anyone suggest some other decent library to do this easily?

```
RSAParameters rsaparam = new RSAParameters(); 
rsaparam.Modulus = modbytes; 
rsaparam.Exponent = expbytes; 
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider() ; 
RSA.ImportParameters(rsaparam); 
byte[] encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by using the [RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx) method. You will also need to use the [RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importparameters.aspx) method and pass it an [RSAParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx) structure (this is where you set the exponent, modulus, etc).

Please have a look at the documentation in the link for the RSAParameters - it's very well documented what parameter you have to pass for what structure-field - should be no problem if you now the algorithm.

EDIT: here is the example straight from the [MSDN-site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx):

```
class RSACSPSample
{

    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {       //initialze the byte arrays to the public key information.
            byte[] PublicKey = {214,46,220,83,160,73,40,39,201,155,19,202,3,11,191,178,56,
                                   74,90,36,248,103,18,144,170,163,145,87,54,61,34,220,222,
                                   207,137,149,173,14,92,120,206,222,158,28,40,24,30,16,175,
                                   108,128,35,230,118,40,121,113,125,216,130,11,24,90,48,194,
                                   240,105,44,76,34,57,249,228,125,80,38,9,136,29,117,207,139,
                                   168,181,85,137,126,10,126,242,120,247,121,8,100,12,201,171,
                                   38,226,193,180,190,117,177,87,143,242,213,11,44,180,113,93,
                                   106,99,179,68,175,211,164,116,64,148,226,254,172,147};

            byte[] Exponent = {1,0,1};

            //Values to store encrypted symmetric keys.
            byte[] EncryptedSymmetricKey;
            byte[] EncryptedSymmetricIV;

            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            //Create a new instance of RSAParameters.
            RSAParameters RSAKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();

            //Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
            RSAKeyInfo.Modulus = PublicKey;
            RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = Exponent;

            //Import key parameters into RSA.
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKeyInfo);

            //Create a new instance of the RijndaelManaged class.
            RijndaelManaged RM = new RijndaelManaged();

            //Encrypt the symmetric key and IV.
            EncryptedSymmetricKey = RSA.Encrypt(RM.Key, false);
            EncryptedSymmetricIV = RSA.Encrypt(RM.IV, false);

            Console.WriteLine("RijndaelManaged Key and IV have been encrypted with RSACryptoServiceProvider."); 

        }
        //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
        //to the console.
        catch(CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that only the key/iv gets encrypted - not arbitrary bytes - the length of those bytes is important too!

The allowed length is described in MSDN an depends on the OS!

Comment: hi, carsten konig, thank you for reply.. i have tried it, but it returns a "BAD DATA" error with cryptographic exception.. any idea, what i may be doing wrong? i have added the code below      `            RSAParameters rsaparam = new RSAParameters();
            rsaparam.Modulus = modbytes;
            rsaparam.Exponent = expbytes;


            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider() ;
            RSA.ImportParameters(rsaparam);
            byte[] encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);'

Comment: i have also tried RSA.FromXmlString(mykey); (where mykey contains an xml string with modulus and exp) but in that also i get a "BAD DATA" errror with cryptographic exception... any idea anybody? or if its some microsoft bug, can anyone suggest some other decent library to do this easily?

Comment: it's hard to tell - was there something in the inner exception? Maybe you got the key-lenth wrong ... thinking of it - you know that the lenght of the data to encrypt has to have a certain length?

Comment: hi mr. carsten konig, no there was nothing on inner exception.. i am kind of giving it up.. Looks like nobody actually ever tried this before. Thank you for all hints and help.

Comment: no I've done similar stuff before - have you checked the length of the block you want to encrypt?

Comment: Does supplying only module is enough for enc(!)ryption ?

Comment: Please note that if your Modulus and Exponent are coming from Java the arrays need to be reversed and 0x00 padding removed from it before reversing

Comment: `RSAKeyInfo.Exponent = Exponent;` - ok, used this for encryption. But what `Exponent` to use for decryption??

Answer (score 4):

If you are using RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString to export the modulus and exponent that the server sends, you need to use Convert.FromBase64String.

```
    public RSAParameters SetPublicKey(string modulus, string exponent)
    {
        RSAParameters result = new RSAParameters();
        result.Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(modulus);
        result.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(exponent);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One additional hint that was very useful for me:

In this line,

```
//Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
SAKeyInfo.Modulus = PublicKey;
```

PublicKey can also be a direct, straightforward, array of bytes that you can get from the "Public Key" field of a X509 Certificate (directly).